# How do I delete text between [ ]?

Tags: subtitle

**Before:**

```
[laughs]    
[Rosie]  
- [all] Oh!  
- [Billy] Okay.
```

**After:**

```
-Oh!  
-Okay.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \s*\[.*?\]\s*
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

Answer (score -1):

it can be used with Subtitle Edit. Thank you for your prompt answer.

Options-->Settings-->General-->Check "Remove blank lines when opening a subtitle".

https://i.postimg.cc/gjHVbkmc/Untitled-2.gif
 - Removing the text for Hearing Impaired

[image: Subtitle Edit]

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with Notepad++ as was asked in the question.

Comment: I agree that it can be improved until we get a more complete answer.
But now we are happy with what we have so far.